# How to know which buttons text should be changed of a div by selecting a value from dropdown in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<tr>
    <td>gggg</td>
    <td>343434343</td>
    <td>gg ggg</td>
    <td>
        <select id="purchase" data-id="<?php echo $arr['cusid']; ?>"
            class="items" name="items">
            <option value="1"
                <?php if($arr['itemstatus']=="Item Picked") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>
                Item Picked
            </option>
        </select>
        <button class="issue modify btn btn-success" id="ref"
            data-id="<?php echo $arr['cusid']; ?>">
            <?php if($arr['issuestatus']=="0") {echo 'Not Issued';} else{ echo 'Issued'; } ?>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a code like this in my html table. I have many rows like this. When I am selecting the Item Picked from the select box, I want to display the text Issued in the button tag with class issue when I am changing the content of the select box.I have written the code for it but when i am changing the select box value in the first row, the text Issued is displaying all the button with the class issue in all other rows. I want to display the text issue in the particular button. The code I have written is shown below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {


$('select.items').on('change', function(e) {


          var text = 'Issued';

          $("button#ref:last").html(text);


          var cusid = $('.items').attr("data-id");



     });

  });


 </script>
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: your code has a `syntax error`. A parenthesis `)` is missing after the curly braces '}'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `this` object inside of the event handler to traverse and select the right element. Here I have used `.next()` since the button is an immediate next sibling to the select element,

```
$('select.items').on('change', function(e) {
  var text = 'Issued';
  var cusid = $(this).data("id");

  $(this).next(".btn.issue").text(text);
});
```

Also using multiple id would make your html invalid. Instead of using same id "ref" for buttons use a class.

Comment: @Divya Glad to help! :-)